# .net MVC equivalent to Page.ParseControl()

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3

We're investigating porting our custom .net webforms CMS over to MVC.

One feature of our current CMS is the ability for the user to add modules ( really just .net user controls ) into the rich text editor. These modules are then parsed into a container.

```
plc_controls.Controls.Add(Page.ParseControl(description));
```

Where 'description' is a field from the database that contains some plain page content, and MAY include one or more user controls in the markup.

How is this sort of thing accommodated in the mvc framework? I'm not quite familiar enough with MVC to know where to begin - at this point we're just investigating whether the move makes sense or not.

**Edited with an example**

Currently, a user can input markup that could look like the following:

```
<p>Some text</p>
<cms:facilities id="facilities" membertypes="2,3,4" runat="server" />
<p>Some more text</p>
```

This is stored in a single database field called 'Description', and in our webforms CMS I parse this description into a control container, as above. cms:facilities is a web user control that's loaded into the pages/control portion of the web.config. The control just renders a list of facilities between the two paragraph tags.

Comment: The short answer is, well, it doesn't. There is no such a thing as a custom control in the ASP.NET MVC framework. You most probably can obtain a similar behavior, using another kind of approach, but we need more information in order to give you a complete answer. For example, do these user controls of yours depend on server-side behavior?

Comment: @rsenna - that's fine, by how would this general concept be handled?

Comment: The closest thing in the ASP.NET MVC framework to the WebForms user controls are "partial views". You could probably start from there.

Comment: @rsenna, yes, I've seen those, but how would I dynamically render them into a view? That's really what needs to happen.

Comment: I guess what your question is really about is this: how an user can add *custom markup*, defined by my web site, in a web rich text editor? When you were working with WebForms, a valid answer was using user controls and `Page.ParseControl`. That is *not* feasible using ASP.NET MVC... But why don't you use something like [markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com)? They give you a complete and free markup editor, and they also allow you to define custom markup.

Comment: @rsenna, I've added an example above - the question is not about how the user enters content / modules, but about how they can be dynamically rendered in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an formal answer, based on I have already said in the comments above. Maybe that make things a little bit clearer.

1. Expose all your user controls as partial views.
2. Define some sort of *special markup* in order to render your content.
3. Implement a custom parser for your custom markup (or use some third-party library for that).
4. Based on the markup, render the final HTML containing all references to the controls chosen by the user.

For example, you could be posting something like this (using a modified [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode)* parser):

```
[p]Some text[/p]
[facilities id="facilities" membertypes="2,3,4"]
[p]Some more text[/p]
```

In fact, this is **much more secure** then posting "HTML with ASP.NET server tags". I do believe that some hacker could use your current rich-edit solution for posting HTML code that could explore some client or server-side backdoor, but maybe I'm wrong...

And again, you **cannot** use the same approach you used to follow with the ASP.NET WebForms version - there is no such thing as server-tags in ASP.NET MVC.

This, of course, is much more complex than your previous ASP.NET WebForms solution. But AFAIK is how you should implement it in ASP.NET MVC (unless there is some third-party library capable of doing that, which I'm not aware of).

Also, sorry if I did not make it clearer from the beginning - English is not my first language, and I'm having some trouble explaining this whole concept to you.

* See [Codekicker.BBCode](http://bbcode.codeplex.com/) for an implementation of BBCode in .NET. In fact AFAIK it could be integrated with [markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) - that would give you an almost complete rich-editor solution, for free.

Comment: Thanks @rsenna. It's more the last step that I'm interested in. I did find this - Clay - part of the Orchard .net open source cms project: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/08/16/clay-malleable-c-dynamic-objects-part-1-why-we-need-it.aspx